# how to auto layout Google maps in Ios

Tags: ios7, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am new to ios and Trying to embed a map to my application. I do not want the map to cover the entire page instead I am looking for the way to auto layout it base on the ipad rotation.

```
GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
```

Google only give an example to show the map with drawing rectangular? Can I show the map in other way that preserves auto layout as well?

Comment: Add constraints to the map view, and it should function just like any other view.

Comment: Is no possible apply constraints in mapView because is created in code, and not by InterfaceBuild. I too looking for this answer. @LeonNatan

Comment: @TiagoAmaral It is possible to apply auto layout constraints by code. There's no need to use interface builder.

Answer (score 2):

Just today implemented the same thing everybody may need too:
Using the [PureLayout library](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout) it's very easy to layout **GMSMapView** like regular `UIView`.

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86 longitude:151.20 zoom:6];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.delegate = self;
// This is important when we layout view with constraints
mapView_.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:mapView_];

// Size to fit the screen with zero insets
[mapView_ autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

You're gonna get the **fullscreen** map view on your screen. It works when you **rotate** the screen as well.

Answer (score 0):

create a rect and pass it to the `[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:frame camera:camera];`

following snipet works for me. Hope it works for u. I created a UIVIEW and I am embedding map on it.

```
CGRect mapRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.mapView.frame.size.width,
                              self.mapView.frame.size.height);
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:mapRect camera:camera];
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [FLKAutoLayout](https://github.com/floriankugler/FLKAutoLayout) to add constraints from code.

Add a container view in Interface Builder and added constraints to fit the entire screen.
In your UIViewController, create your GMSMapView and add those lines

```
container.addSubview(mapView)

mapView.constrainWidthToView(container, predicate: nil)
mapView.constrainHeightToView(container, predicate: nil)
```

This is Swift code but it work on Objective-C too.

Now the GMSMapView fit the container view with rotation support

Answer (score 0):

You can add it through interface builder lake any other custom views and to apply the required constraints there:

1. place a `UIView` object anywhere inside your `ViewController`
2. apply any required constraints as usual
3. set the `UIView` class `GMSMapView` under `Identity Inspector` tab of interface builder (like you do for any other custom views)
4. connect `GMSMapView` as `IBOutlet` with your `ViewController`
5. provide any further customizations for `GMSMapView` instance to have a desired behavior.

I was actually concerned if it's possible to init `GMSMapView` without call to

```
[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
```

since this is what google quick start page shows as example. It appeared that it's absolutely fine to set camera (if required for your app) after the GMSMapView instance is created like this :

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86 longitude:151.20 zoom:10];
self.googleMapView.camera = camera;
```

*self.googleMapView is IBOutlet from the steps above.